# does currentLine acts as a keyword in java?

Tags: java

I see this line of code which surprised me:

```
String res = "", currentLine;    
while ((currentLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            res+= currentLine;

        }
```

the variable currentLine is not defined anywhere before and strangely it does nt throw any error? Does java somehow makes currentLine a keyword here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, `currentLine` *is* defined:

```
String res = "", currentLine;
```

is the same as

```
String res = "";
String currentLine;
```